# How to make gcloud snapshot or image public from personal project

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am pretty new to gcloud. I was wondering if there was a way to make a snapshot or image that exists in your personal project public so other people could copy the snapshot or image into their own project? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Public images are, in effect, curated by Google; see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) for details. You can certainly create a private image and [export it to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) for sharing, though! (I don't think this is possible for snapshots.)